# passing current date and time separately into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Hello i am passing some data into the sqlLite database and i want to send current date and time separately. I am quite new to programming so any help would be owesome. I checked and other data is getting stored correctly.

```
        public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vas_podatki.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "podatki";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "JAKOST";
    public static final String COL_3 = "DAN";
    public static final String COL_4 = "URA";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, JAKOST INTEGER, DAN CURRENT_DATE , URA CURRENT_TIME )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(String jakost){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,jakost);
        long reuslt = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (reuslt == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to store them separately?  If you just stored the UTC timestamp then you can work out the date and time whenever you need in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void addVacantEntry(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + MyDatabaseColums.VacantEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + MyDatabaseColums.VacantEntry.V_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + MyDatabaseColums.VacantEntry.Date + " NUMERIC);");
```

if you want to save Date time in Sqlite   , attribute Type will be **NUMERIC**

and to Store it  Get datetime in **Long**

Like this

```
   private long  date_in_long() {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Syear, Smonth, Sday, Shoure, Sminute);
            long startDate = c.getTimeInMillis();

            return startDate;
        }
```

Comment: doesn't column spelling in query will contain 'n' too or that is correct?

Comment: more explain please

Comment: in your query in add method

Comment: No this method Just to Get datatime as Long

Comment: then you save it in your database